# Protect nginx from hammering

Tags: security, scraping

I would like to protect my nginx+pessenger+rails3 HTTP server from hammering/scraping. If you try to scrape the Google it shows you a captcha in case you make too many requests from the same IP. What module should I use?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can throttle connections with the following

http://wiki.nginx.org/NginxHttpLimitReqModule

Comment: Hey... thanks for the answer! Do you know what is the usual configuration for it?

Comment: @xpepermint: The documentation linked to in the answer gives examples.

Comment: Hey... I'm asking for the best practice info ...